# AIR for Android: toggle SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Tags: android, air

I want to toggle SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or  SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE flag when compiling with AIR for ANDROID, but I don't know how to to this. Probably I had to modify the name_of_app.xml ...

I want to 'try' to switch off the menu bar in an Android Tablet, but every methods I try are a mess ....

Any Help ??

Massimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the statusbar (the bar at the top), you need to go fullscreen. You can do this either in your app.xml by setting `<fullscreen>true</fullscreen>` or in your app at runtime by setting `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

If you are trying to hide the menubar (the soft-navigation present at the bottom of Nexus devices and a limited number of other Android devices), this will set those buttons to be in their minified state as well (they are not hidden, but are set to a simple glowing circle rather than the icon). I do not know if it is possible through AIR to hide the menubar completely. It should be possible using an AIR Native Extension, assuming it is possible at all, but that may (likely is) more trouble than it is worth for such a simple task.

For future reference, you can't set most Android flags through AIR. It simply is not supported. You can set `uses-permission` and `uses-feature` in your app.xml as Manifest additions, but that is it.